# What semantic notions underlie "mouth" and "so, to such an extent", for 咁?

Tags: etymology

This is a common word, so I don't know why  [Taiwan's Ministry of Education](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi#X) omits this character,

[image]

and why [CUHK doesn't exhibit any etymology](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%92%81). Wiktionary has the same Glyph Origin, but I quote [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?searchChinese=1&zi=%E5%92%81) for it's trustworthier?

[image]

Comment: "trustworthier", **you are kidding** :(

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I'm afraid no. I edited my post to prove that I tried 4 search engines, but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some dictionaries deliberately ignore characters for Cantonese.

In Cantonese, it is very common to borrow homophonous characters to represent another meaning, especially spoken words with forgotten source or words come from foreign. To prevent confusion, mark them with semantic component 口 to indicate them as spoken form.

Spoken Cantonese:

- 咁, borrow and differential from 甘
- 嘅, borrow and differential from 既
- 嘢, borrow and differential from 野
- 吓, (一吓, 兩吓) differential from other meanings of 下 (now 下 only)

Foreign:

- 吋 = British inches (differentiate from Chinese 寸)
- 呎 = British feet (differentiate from Chinese 尺)
- = England/English (now written as 英 only)
- 咭唎 = 英吉利 = England/English (Britain/British)
- 嗬囒 = 荷蘭 = Holland (the Netherlands)